# How do I remove/add a file to stage that is deleted/untracked due to renaming folder

Tags: node.js, git, rename, stage, isomorphic-git

**Use Case**

- Copy the folder along with it's files using `fs.copyFile` by iterating over the paths of files that folder has.
- Delete the files in the folder that was copied using `fs.unlinkSync`
- Remove the now deleted files from git index using `git.remove`
- Add the copied files to staging using `git.add` and commit.

**Current State**

- Deleted files show up when using `git status`, marked as deleted.
- The copied files also show up marked as untracked

```js
fs.copyFile(oldPath, newPath, async err => {
  if (err) 
    return console.log(err)

  // Delete the old file
  await fs.unlinkSync(oldPath)
  // Remove the old file from git index
  await git.remove({
    dir,
    filepath: path.basename(oldPath)
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
})
```

**Problem**

- Since there's now both deleted & untracked file with same name, passing the just filename to `filepath` won't work(a guess) since there are now two files of same name.

**Expected Solution**

- While using `git mv` command it removes the deleted file from index and adds the copied file to staging, how can I replicate this functionality with isomorphic-git

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to pass the relative path to filepath field so that would the relative path to the file from the repository directory

```js
await git.remove({
    dir,
    filepath: relativePath
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
```